# Twitter Bootstrap - minimum characters

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap have a plugin, that will make you able to limt characters in a textarea field.

See it here:
http://jvashishtha.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#limit


I was wondering how to change the plugin in to do the opposite. To require the user to enter in at least 200 characters.

Comment: what have you tried so far? What should happen if not enough text was written?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're getting ready to dive into the wonderful world of form validation. You can write your own code for this if you like, but if you've got anything more than a handful of fields it can quickly get quite complicated.

You're probably better off using a validation framework like [jQuery Validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation). The docs are pretty good and should help you through it all.

Out of the box jQuery Validation doesn't format error messages in the way Bootstrap expects. [This example](http://alittlecode.com/jquery-form-validation-with-styles-from-twitter-bootstrap/) looks like a good place to look for hooking that up.